# Finding Parabolas based solely on arbitrary point and line.

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry

Suppose one is given a point $(a,b)$ and a line $cx+dy+e=0$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $c$ and $d$ are not both equal to zero. How (if possible) would one give an equation of a parabola with focus as the given point and directrix the given line? I would argue it is clear how it should be done if $c=0$ or $d=0$, but what would change otherwise?

Comment: For any (non-circle) conic with eccentricity $e$ (which is $1$ for a parabola), $$(\text{distance from $(x,y)$ to focus})^2 =e^2 (\text{distance from $(x,y)$ to line})^2$$ Do you know the formulas for the distance between two points and the distance from a point to a line?

Comment: Not for between a point and a line?

Comment: For the line $cx+dy+e=0$, [the distance formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line#Line_defined_by_an_equation) is $$\frac{|cx+dy+e|}{\sqrt{c^2+d^2}}$$ If you leave off the absolute value, you get a "signed" distance, which encodes information about *which side* of the line a point is on. (Of course, distance $0$ means "on the line".) Be that as it may, squaring eliminates the need for the absolute value ... it also conveniently removes the square roots.

Comment: Ah. So $$(x-a)^2 +(y-b)^2 = \frac{(cx+dy+e)^2}{c^2+d^2}.$$

Comment: Bingo! ... You can/should confirm a related formula. Clear the fractions and expand everything out, until you get something of the form $A x^2 + B xy + C y^2 + \cdots = 0$. Verify that $B^2-4AC=0$ for the parabola. (If you keep the $e^2$ factor, the value won't be zero, but you'll see how $e$ itself affects the sign.)

Comment: Will it necessarily be able to solve for $y$? Or $x$ that is?

Comment: What you do with the equation depends upon what you need. If you need "just some equation" for the parabola, then write the form you have, declare victory, and go home. If you need to compare your result to someone else's, or you just want to clean it up, then manipulate it into the "general" form $Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2+Dx+Ey+F=0$; comparing versions then amounts to checking that they match (up to a possible multiplier). If you plan to *plot* the equation, then solve for $y$ (or $x$), as desired. (For that, you'll probably want to get things to "general" form first, then solve the quadratic equation.)

Comment: This is all summarized succinctly [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabola#General_case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of the parabola is:

> A parabola is the geometrical locus of the points for which the distances from a point of coords $(a,b)$ and a line (the directrix of the parabola) are equal.

Let $P(x,y)$. By Pythagora's theorem, we know that the distance from $P$ to $A(a,b)$ is:
$$\sqrt{(x-a)^2 +(y-b)^2}$$

And, by the distance formula, we have:
$$\frac{cx+dy+e}{\sqrt{c^2+d^2}}$$

This two lenght have to be equal, so the equation becomes:
$$\sqrt{(x-a)^2 +(y-b)^2}=\frac{cx+dy+e}{\sqrt{c^2+d^2}} \leftrightarrow (x-a)^2 +(y-b)^2=\frac{(cx+dy+e)^2}{c^2+d^2}$$